# React-router-dom: Very simple nested routing does not work

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom, react-router-redux, react-router-component

I have searched through different tutorials and multiple stackOverflow questions. And none of which, helped me solve a very basic problem:
**Implement nested routes with react-router-dom**
Here's my code so far:

> App.js

```
  <Route exact path="/home" name="Home" component={DefaultLayout} />
```

> DefaultLayout.js

```
 <Route path="/home/users" component={Users} />
```

When I go to **/home/users**, I get a blank screen because react-router-dom is looking-up the definition of that route inside **App.js** instead of searching it inside **DefaultLayout.js**..
So I have two questions:
**QUESION 1:** What am I doing wrong exactly?
**QUESTION 2:** How does react-router-dom know that it should look for the nested route inside **DefaultLayout.js** instead of inside **App.js**?

It has been two days and I still cannot solve this simple problem.
Any help is very much appreciated.
**EDIT 1:** I have started a new project just for the sake of implementing a very simple nested routing:

> App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import ParentComponent from "./nestedComponents/ParentComponent";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/home" name="Home" component={ParentComponent} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

> ParentComponent.js

```
import React from "react";
import nestedComponentOne from "./nestedComponentOne";
import nestedComponentTwo from "./nestedComponentTwo";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

export default function ParentComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      PARENT COMPONENT
      <Switch>
        <Route path="home/nestedComponentOne" component={nestedComponentOne} />
        <Route path="home/nestedComponentTwo" component={nestedComponentTwo} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

> nestedComponentOne.js

```
import React from "react";

export default function nestedComponentOne() {
  return <div>NESTED COMPONENT 1</div>;
}
```

> nestedComponentTwo.js

```
import React from "react";

export default function nestedComponentTwo() {
  return <div>NESTED COMPONENT 2</div>;
}
```

But, I still get a blank screen whenever I try to access a nested component...

Answer (score 0):

You have this problem:

[React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writing manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually)

The simplest fix is to replace the BrowserRouter with a HashRouter